# auto-wiring generic decorators using Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have two decorators:

```cs
class DbCommandWithTransactionHandlerDecorator<TCommand>
    : IDbCommandHandler<TCommand> { ... }

class DbOptimisticConcurrencyRetryDecorator<TCommand>
    : IDbCommandHandler<TCommand> { ... }
```

These decorators add transaction management and optimistic-concurrency retry capability to a database command.

I am using Autofac as my IoC container.  I would like to setup Autofac such that it will auto-wire all `IDbCommandHandler<>` found in an assembly, such that when I request say an `IDbCommandHandler<CreateNewNotificationCommand>`, it will automatically decorate it with first a `DbCommandWithTransactionHandlerDecorator`, and then a `DbOptimisticConcurrencyRetryDecorator`.

I've been trying to get this with Autofac's `builder.RegisterGenericDecorator()`, but haven't yet managed.  The main issue is that a decorator requires a 'named' argument to work. Below is the sample code that is most 'near' to what I want to achieve - However the main flaw is that I still had to manually register the types.

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
var a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

// I need to find a way how these can be 'auto-wired', 
// rather than having to manually wire each command.

builder.RegisterType<CreateNewNotificationCommandHandler>()
    .Named<IDbCommandHandler<CreateNewNotificationCommand>>("command");
builder.RegisterType<CreateNewNotificationCommandHandler_2>()
    .Named<IDbCommandHandler<CreateNewNotificationCommand_2>>("command");

builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(
    typeof(DbCommandWithTransactionHandlerDecorator<>),
    typeof(IDbCommandHandler<>),
    fromKey: "command");

var container = builder.Build();
var handler1 =
  container.Resolve<IDbCommandHandler<CreateNewNotificationCommand>>();
var handler2 =
  container.Resolve<IDbCommandHandler<CreateNewNotificationCommand_2>>();
handler1.Handle(null); //these are correctly decorated
handler2.Handle(null); //these are correctly decorated
```

Comment: @Steven I did manage to find a workaround for Autofac, which involved doing a manual reflection search for types, and mapping them.  However earlier today I tried Simple Injector as I had seen it mentioned in the article you posted yesterday - All I can say is that it works really brilliant and very simple-to-use - kudos to that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did manage to find a workaround via reflection, which although it works is not really elegant. I will post it below for completeness sake:

```
 public interface IDbCommandHandler<in TCommand>: IDbCommandHandlerStub
    where TCommand : IDbCommand
{
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}

public interface IDbCommandHandlerStub
{

}

    private List<Type> getTypesThatImplementIDbCommandHandler(IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblyList)
    {
        List<Type> list = new List<Type>();
        foreach (var a in assemblyList)
        {
            var matches = a.GetTypes().Where(t => typeof(IDbCommandHandlerStub).IsAssignableFrom(t));
            list.AddRange(matches);
        }
        return list;
    }

private void registerDbCommands(List<Type> dbCommandHandlerTypes, ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        foreach (var t in dbCommandHandlerTypes)
        {
            var interfaces = t.GetInterfaces();
            foreach (var i in interfaces)
            {
                builder.RegisterType(t).Named("dbCommand", i);
            }

        }
    }


   public void Test1()
   {
        ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        var dbCommandHandlerTypes = getTypesThatImplementIDbCommandHandler(assemblies);
        registerDbCommands(dbCommandHandlerTypes, builder);            

        builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(typeof(DbCommandWithTransactionHandlerDecorator<>),
                                        typeof(IDbCommandHandler<>),
                                        fromKey: "dbCommand", toKey:"dbCommandWithTransaction").SingleInstance();

        builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(typeof(DbOptimisticConcurrencyRetryDecorator<>),
                                        typeof(IDbCommandHandler<>),
                                        fromKey: "dbCommandWithTransaction").SingleInstance();

        var container = builder.Build();
        var handler1 = container.Resolve<IDbCommandHandler<CreateNewNotificationCommand>>();

}
```

First, I get via reflection all the types that implement `IDbCommandHandler`.  Then, I register them as named types for all the interfaces which they implement, giving them a name of 'dbCommand'.

Then, I register the generic decorator to decorate types named 'dbCommand'.  This decorater is named 'dbCommandWithTransaction', and is used to then register another generic decorator for the concurrency-retry.

Considering this is something which would be done once and 'forgotten', I was ready go with this workaround.  However, I was trying out other IoC containers and came upon [Simple Injector](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Advanced-scenarios#Generic_Decorators), and all this can be done in just two lines of code - And have since then won me over.